# Php MySQL Order by date (custom)

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

Here's my PHP/SQL Request

```
<?php $events = $wpdb->get_results( 
    "
    SELECT * 
    FROM  `wp_em_events` 
    LIMIT 5
    // HERE'S MY ORDER BY DATE
    "
);

$dt = new DateTime($event->event_start_date);
$formattedDate = $dt->format('d M Y');

foreach ( $events as $event ) 
{

echo '<div class="home-event">';
    echo $formattedDate;
    echo $event->event_name;
echo '</div>';

}

?>
```

According to a table containaing a column "**event_start_date**" where values looks like these :

```
2013-03-27 
2013-04-03
2013-03-31
```

**I want to order my events by those date (the closest to us first)**

I tried a single

```
ORDER BY event_start_date DESC
```

But it "burn" my request

------- BONUS QUESTION --------

How could I increment my events in order to have :

```
<div class="home-event-1">
<div class="home-event-2">
<div class="home-event-3">
...
```

Thank you very much !!

Comment: I can't imagine what a burnt request looks like...

Comment: You must be feelin smoky out there.

Comment: I'm french so excuse me if my vocabulary is not as huge as yours... But thank you for this awesome answer. It crashed my request, make it display nothing.

Comment: I wasn't trying to be humorous at all, but if you're not a native speaker it's probably better to avoid slang (argot) as it will most likely confuse people that don't share your mother tongue...

Comment: I just didn't know the right word, that's why I used the first which had sense to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ORDER BY` comes *before* the `LIMIT`. You'll want:

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM
    `wp_em_events` 
ORDER BY
    event_start_date DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Also, you're fetching the date in the wrong place. It'll need to be *within* the iteration:

```
foreach ( $events as $event ) 
{

  $dt = new DateTime($event->event_start_date);

  $formattedDate = $dt->format('d M Y');

  // ...
```

As for the increments:

```
foreach ( $events as $key => $event ) 
{

    echo '<div class="home-event-' . ($key + 1) . '">';
    echo $formattedDate;
    echo $event->event_name;
    echo '</div>';

}
```

Assuming `$events` is not an associate array, of course. If it is:

```
$i = 0;

foreach ( $events as $event ) 
{

    echo '<div class="home-event-' . ++$i . '">';
    echo $formattedDate;
    echo $event->event_name;
    echo '</div>';

}
```

Comment: Perfect, I didn't knew that. Thank you for not being as "funny" as the other answers :)

Comment: Any idea for the class="" incrementation ?